# Quantifying similarity between two representation methods

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

Given, a set of entities, which are represented in two different representation spaces. Is there any existing way to quantify how similar two representation spaces are i.e. to what extend, order of closeness between points is preserved?

Given: set of entities $(e_1, e_2, e_3 , \ldots, e_n)$, corresponding representations in $j$-dimensional space $(v_1, v_2, v_3 , \ldots, v_n)$ corresponding representation in $k$-dimensional space $(u_1, u_2, u_3 , \ldots, u_n)$

Output: Measure of similarity between $j$-dimensional space and $k$-dimensional space

Comment: Are the spaces both Euclidean, Metric, etc?

Comment: You could try mutual information.

Answer (score 0):

If the two different representations or feature vectors are related by some output/behavioral function, you could try representation dissimilarity matrices (RDMs), which have been used in the field of computational neuroscience to compare artificial neural network feature representations with that of organic brains via comparing the similarity of response patterns to varying stimuli in each type of modality (making the final comparison between feature vectors agnostic to their dimensionality). Here are a couple of papers that implement that approach:

- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2605405/
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25375136

From the Khaligh-Razavi & Kriegeskorte paper (2nd link):

"RSA enables us to relate representations obtained from different modalities (e.g. computational models and fMRI patterns) by comparing the dissimilarity patterns of the representations. In this framework representational dissimilarity matrices (RDMs) are used for making the link between different modalities. RDM is a square symmetric matrix in which the diagonal entries reflect comparisons between identical stimuli and are 0, by definition. Each off-diagonal value indicates the dissimilarity between the activity patterns associated with two different stimuli. RDM summarizes the information carried by a given representation from an area in the brain or a computational model.

We had 96 stimuli, of which half were animates and the other half were inanimates. To calculate the RDM for a brain region or a computational model, a 96×96 matrix was made in which each cell was filled with the dissimilarity value between the response patterns elicited by two stimuli. For each pair of stimuli, the dissimilarity measure was 1 minus the Pearson correlation between the response patterns elicited by those stimuli in a brain region or a computational model."